# How to check a condition on a list (or array) and then sort the elements based on that condition in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, complex-numbers

I have a list of complex numbers with n elements, I want to check that how many of the elements are real (the imaginary part is zero) and then sort my list in a way that it starts with the real numbers.

For example for the list below:

```
a = [ 7 + 0j, -2 + 3j, -2 - 3j, 5 + 6j, 5 - 6j, -1+ 0j, -8 + 4j, -8 - 4j]
```

two elements are real ( first element and sixth element) I want to know that I have 2 real elements in my list and then I want to have a sort like below that starts with real numbers and the other elements remains unchanged:

```
b = [ 7 + 0j, -1+ 0j, -2 + 3j, -2 - 3j, 5 + 6j, 5 - 6j, -8 + 4j, -8 - 4j]
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try something by yourself to solve the problem?

Comment: @FUNNYDMAN No actually. I'm pretty new to Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the numbers by comparing their imaginary part against zero. Those with 0's will come first, remaining numbers will be unchanged in their order.

```
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x:x.imag!=0)
print(a)
```

Outputs

```
[(7+0j), (-1+0j), (-2+3j), (-2-3j), (5+6j), (5-6j), (-8+4j), (-8-4j)]
```

To get number of such entries use

```
sum(x.imag == 0 for x in a)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there any way to count the numbers of elements with zero imaginary part?

Answer (score 2):

Python has a [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sorting.html#sorting-basics) function that takes a `key` argument.

> The value of the key parameter should be a function that takes a
>   single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes.

You can sort based on a lambda function that checks the presence of non zero imaginary component.

```
a = [ 7 + 0j, -2 + 3j, -2 - 3j, 5 + 6j, 5 - 6j, -1+ 0j, -8 + 4j, -8 - 4j]
sorted(a, key = lambda x: x.imag != 0) 
#Output: [(7+0j), (-1+0j), (-2+3j), (-2-3j), (5+6j), (5-6j), (-8+4j), (-8-4j)]
```